# Assign Table structure to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please consider this structure:

```
          1   |    2     |    3    | ....
----------------------------------------------------------
2016      100     2000       500
2015      540     450        1200
2014      120     230        660
```

I want to assign this values to an variable and access to value such this way: `MyVar[2016][2]` or call a function that return the value for year:2016 and month:2.

What is the best solution to convert that data to structure that can assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var MyVar = { "2014": [0, 120, 230, 660], "2015": [0, 540, 450, 1200], "2016": [0, 100, 2000, 500] };
console.log(MyVar["2016"][2]); //2000
```